# jQuery sortable connected-lists inline

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I'm referring to this link here: [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists)

I want to make these items inline, and I've changed the display of the

```
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li
```

to

```
display:inline;
```

in the css, but then all gets scrambled and my items fly off to the right, even though I have div wrapper set which is 500px - they fly out of that area.

Has anyone some good tips to handle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your css to:

```
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: @Nicholas Murray: no unfortunately not. I will reply in few mins the link to the screenshot so you can see. 
edit:here is the link to the screenshot: http://www.filedropper.com/capture_15

Comment: @Nikola - thats not happening for me if I visit the sortable site and change the css in firebug to the css that I have posted above.

Comment: @Nicholas Murray: hmmm, yes, I've tried that now and this is what I get: http://www.filedropper.com/jquersortables

Comment: @Nikola - thats what I get but they are not scrambled or flying off to the right.

Comment: @Nicholas Murray: do you have any suggestions on how could I "restrict" them with a div or something like that so they wouldn't go outside that div. I mean this is obviously because of my css file, but I can't seem to put a finger on where the problem might be.. Anyway I'll accept your answer as you were then only one even trying to answer, so thank you.

Comment: @Nikola - upload a screen shot to file dropper of the way you'd like it to appear